# Additional condition in SQL's join

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

Assume that we have two tables in SQL database (I'm using PostgreSQL in case the answer depends on the database):

```
CREATE TABLE testA
(
    id integer,
    checked boolean
)

CREATE TABLE testB
(
    id integer,
    testA_id integer
)
```

I want to do a select from `testB` joined with `testA` and get all results which are `checked`. There are two ways:

```
SELECT tA.*, tB.*
FROM testB AS tB
JOIN testA AS tA
    ON (tA.id = tB.testA_id AND tA.checked)
```

or

```
SELECT tA.*, tB.*
FROM testB AS tB
JOIN testA AS tA
    ON tA.id = tB.testA_id
WHERE
    tA.checked
```

Which way is preferred? And are there performance differences?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the `WHERE` clause filters the results. The `ON` just defines the way the tables are joined together. In your example there would be no difference.

But take a look at the following:

```
CREATE TABLE testA
(
    id integer,
    checked boolean
)

CREATE TABLE testB
(
    id integer,
    testA_id integer,
    checked boolean
)
```

As you can see i have added a checked column in TestB.

There might be rows in TableA that have no rows in TableB Like the following data:

**TestA**

```
ID|checked
1|true
2|true
3|false
```

**TestB**

```
ID|testA_id|checked
1|1|true
2|1|false
3|3|true
```

As you can see there is no TestB for TestA id = 2

Now, let's assume you want to display **ALL** TestA rows along with the checked TableB rows (if any).

So you need a left join:

**First Case**

```
SELECT tA.*, tB.*
FROM testB AS tB
LEFT JOIN testA AS tA
    ON (tA.id = tB.testA_id AND tB.checked)
```

**Reults**

```
ID|checked|ID|testA_id|checked
1|true|1|1|true
2|true|null|null|null
3|false||3|3|true
```

ID 1, 2 and 3 of TableA is returned and if there is a checked TableB row then we return that too.

**Second Case**

```
SELECT tA.*, tB.*
FROM testB AS tB
LEFT JOIN testA AS tA
    ON tA.id = tB.testA_id
WHERE
    tB.checked
```

**Reults**

```
ID|checked|ID|testA_id|checked
1|true|1|1|true
3|false||3|3|true
```

In this case only IDs 1 and 3 are returned because we **filter** the results to show only the ones that have TableB checked.

Answer (score 1):

No performance differences, the optimizer takes care of it, so the two queries are actually the same. You can confirm by using [`EXPLAIN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-explain.html) on your query.